# Repair script for VMS rebuild cannot extract VMX filename on Windows (message: "Ambiguous redirect")

Tags: windows, bash, vmware

I have a corrupted VMX file, and this [link](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1023880) states that this code below can fix this, the problem is i use windows, and not linux, i solved this problem by installing Cygwin.

```
VMXFILENAME=$(sed -n 's/^.*Config file: .*\/\(.\+\)$/\1/p' vmware.log)
echo -e "#\041/usr/bin/vmware" > ${VMXFILENAME}
echo '.encoding = "UTF-8"' >> ${VMXFILENAME}
sed -n '/DICT --- CONFIGURATION/,/DICT ---/ s/^.*DICT \+\(.\+\) = \(.\+\)$/\1 = "\2"/p' vmware.log >> ${VMXFILENAME}
```

the error i get states ambiguous redirect but i just copied the code

```
$ ./vmxrebuild.sh
./vmxrebuild.sh: line 2: ${VMXFILENAME}: ambiguous redirect
./vmxrebuild.sh: line 3: ${VMXFILENAME}: ambiguous redirect
./vmxrebuild.sh: line 4: ${VMXFILENAME}: ambiguous redirect
```

Perhaps solving this problem will help alot of people in the same situation

examples from the config file /log file:

```
2015-09-23T15:04:53.841+02:00| vmx| I120: scsi0:0: Command WRITE(10) took 1.285 seconds (ok)
2015-09-23T15:04:53.847+02:00| vmx| I120: scsi0:0: Command WRITE(10) took 1.272 seconds (ok)
2015-09-23T08:02:50.918+02:00| vmx| I120: Common: MSR      0x485 =         0x100401e5
2015-09-23T08:02:50.918+02:00| vmx| I120: Common: MSR      0x486 =         0x80000021
2015-09-23T08:02:50.918+02:00| vmx| I120: Common: MSR      0x487 =         0xffffffff
2015-09-23T08:02:50.918+02:00| vmx| I120: Common: MSR      0x488 =             0x2000
2015-09-23T08:02:50.918+02:00| vmx| I120: Common: MSR      0x489 =           0x1727ff
```

also it does contains alot of jibberish which i didnt include

Comment: adding `echo "$VMXFILENAME"` after your 1st line will probably show that it is empty.

Comment: it appears indeed to be empty..

Comment: Can you post the or a few of the line(s) containing `Config file` from your `vmware.log`?

Comment: Michael,  i have posted a few lines from my vmware.log,

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing the `sed` regular expression

```
's/^.*Config file: .*\/\(.\+\)$/\1/p'
```

with this one:

```
's/^.*Config file: .*\\\(.\+\)$/\1/p'
```

Similar to the original returning the filename after the last slash (`/`), this will yield the filename after the last backslash (`\`).